# Sequential first order reaction graph in chemical kinetics

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics

In graph given below is a sequential first order reaction

$$\ce{A ->[$k_1$] B ->[$k_2$] C}$$

For $k_2 \gg k_1$ the graph of concentration of $\ce{A}$, $\ce{B}$ and $\ce{C}$ is as follows.

[image]

Won't the graph of the concentrations of $\ce{B}$ and $\ce{C}$ be the same as if $\ce{B}$ is formed then only $\ce{C}$ will be formed simultaneously? Then why is $\ce{C}$'s graph different?

Comment: The answer to your doubt is directly on your graph.  First some B has to be created. Initially, the rate of C formation is zero.

Comment: My doubt is if B is only not formed then will C form? Then why the graph of concentration is different?

Comment: Neither of questions is clear. Try to reformulate. // C is formed only from B. If no B is present, no C is being formed.

Comment: The concentration profiles of B and C are not the same because B is formed only from A and then B only forms C so the concentration of B rises and falls but C only rises as it does not react to form anything else.

Comment: @porphyrin thanku sir

Comment: [Somewhat related](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/64576/30836)

Comment: How much calculus do you know?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo sir i know quite a bit

Comment: Are the two reactions elementary?  Can one assume mass action kinetics?

Comment: See also  [Pre-equilibrium approximation](https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/Johns_Hopkins_University/030.356_Advanced_Inorganic_Laboratory/03%3A_Lab_EF-_Chemical_Kinetics/3.04%3A_Pre-equilibrium_approximation) for k1 >> k2 and [Steady State Approximation](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Kinetics/03%3A_Rate_Laws/3.02%3A_Reaction_Mechanisms/3.2.06%3A_Steady_State_Approximation) for k1 << k2.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/40785/meaning-of-steady-state-kinetics/40796#40796

Answer (score 1):

This question is about the **rate-determining step** of multi-step reactions. Bear in mind that the overall rate of reaction is equal to the slowest step of the reaction, in which case, from $\ce{A}$ to $\ce{B}$ ($k_2 \gg k_1$). Since it is a first-order reaction, the overall reaction rate = $k_1 [\ce{A}]$. The graph of concentration vs time for a first-order reaction should be like $y = \frac1x$.

On the other hand, $\ce{B}$ is the **reaction intermediate**. $[\ce{B}]$ initially increases when the reactant $\ce{A}$ is gradually consumed. But soon, $[\ce{B}]$ reduces to form $\ce{C}$.

The graph of $[\ce{C}]$ must be symmetrical about the horizontal line $y = \frac12[\ce{A}]$ because as stated earlier, the overall reaction rate $= k_1 [\ce{A}]$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pseudo first-order reaction. The rate of product formation is:

$$
\mathrm{R} = \dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\ce{[C]}= k_2\ce{[B]} \tag{1}\\
$$

Applying steady state approximation:

$$
\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\ce{[B]}= k_1\ce{[A]} - k_2\ce{[B]} \approx 0 \tag{2}
$$

$$
\implies k_1\ce{[A]} \approx k_2\ce{[B]}\\
\implies k_1\ce{[A]} \approx k_2\ce{[B]}
$$

Substituting in Equation (1):

$$
R \approx k_1\ce{[A]} 
$$

For the overall reaction $\ce{A -> C}$:

$$
-\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\ce{[A]} = k_1\ce{[A]}\\
\implies \ce{[A]} = \ce{[A]_o}\mathrm{e}^{-k_1t} \tag{3}
$$

Comment: Are you assuming mass action kinetics?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo it is applicable for low concentrations.

Comment: Do you mean (1) is applicable?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo (1), (2), and (3).